# PHP and JQUERY Chained select issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select, chained

I have used a JQUERY and PHP chained select function on the following website.

http://outsideinmatepkg.com/

I am told that the function isn't working for US audience. I have tested this for UK, Middle East, Canada. It works in all browsers i.e Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari. It works for Laptops, Tablets and Cell Phones.

The strange thing is, the whole site works in USA but with the exception of this particular feature. This is new to me. How do I debug as I don't live in US. Can you guys take a look at the script and see if it works in US. Following are the steps.

At home page, scroll down and click on Arizona.
next page, you'll see the drop down menu. Please select second option i.e Florence, AZ
it should load another drop down menu. Please select Florence Correctional Center
This should load another drop down menu. Please select Test by me 1
This should load another drop down and an submit button. select a value and click Submit.

This works every where except for US audience. Any comments or if you may test and give me your feedback.

Thanks,

Faisal

Comment: I'm in the US, seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks mate. Its a good news as it works in US. Have you tested on Mac or Windows platform.